# Angular - Modify component property in app.component.html

Tags: angular

I have a component named "input-text" which just have html textbox in it.

```
<input type="text" />
```

Now, I am using this component in my app.component.html but I want to change the type of this textbox to email, password, etc.

```
<app-input-text>??</app-input-text>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`input.component.ts`

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-input",
  template: `
    <input [type]="type" />
  `
})
export class InputComponent {
  @Input() type: String;
}
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Stack Overflow</h2>
      <app-input type="text"></app-input>
      <app-input type="checkbox"></app-input>
      <app-input type="radio"></app-input>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

This is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/21p1y9vqqj

Comment: Cool. And how can I modify the styles of input in app-component?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to go with `component` way, you could just add `@Input() type: string` and in html use it

#### input-text.component.ts

```
export class InputTextComponent {
   @Input() type: string
}
```

#### input-text.component.html file

```
<input [attr.type]="type" />
```

#### and in element which contains input-text.component

```
<app-input-text [type]="inputType"></app-input-text>
where `inputType` is string type for input like `email, password, text...`
```